# Median in Prolog

Tags: prolog, median

I'm trying to write rules for prolog that define a median of a list by using a partitioning method.

```
partition([], V, [], []).
partition([X | L], V, [X | A], B) :- (V > X), !, partition(L, V, A, B).
partition([X | L], V, A, [X | B]) :- (V < X), !, partition(L, V, A, B).
partition([X | L], V, A, B) :- (V =:= X), partition(L, V, A, B).

median([A], A).
median(L, M) :- partition(L, M, A, B), length(A, X), length(B, X).
```

`partition(L, V, A, B)` partitions list L into 2 sublists A and B with A having values less than V and B having values greater than V.

That part works fine, but when I try to write my median, I'm trying to say that it is a median when after partitioning, A and B are the same length.

median works when I use concrete values, like `median([1, 2, 3], 2)`

but when I try `median([1, 2, 3], X).`

it gives an error message `ERROR: >/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated`.

I was wondering how to fix that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`=:=` operator requires both its operands to be instantiated. When you ask for `median([1, 2, 3], X)`, one of its operands becomes `X`, which is not instantiated yet. The same problem is with other arithmetic operators like `>`.

To correct it, you can either use constraints programming (which provides arithmetic operators that aren't so strict) or rework your program to only use arithmetic on list elements. For example, try a classical approach like: sort the list of numbers, then divide the list into three segments: list of length N, a single element, list of length N. Hint: you can do the part after sorting using just a single `append/3` and two `length/2` invocations.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way to make your program work with `median([1, 2, 3], X)` query - is to instantiate `M` to a member of `L` in the last rule:

```
median(L, M) :- 
    member(M, L), 
    partition(L, M, A, B), length(A, X), length(B, X).
```